# How to remove the excerpt in the Dzonia Lite theme

Tags: php, functions, excerpt

I am using Dzonia Lite theme  in my website. My front page shows all the latest posts. I am getting an excerpt at the end of each post.

Could anyone suggest me how to remove that excerpt at the end of the post.

## Below is the code that I have in my template file

```
<div class="post_content">

    <?php if ((function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())) { ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <?php the_post_thumbnail('post_thumbnail', array('class' => 'postimg')); ?>

    </a>

    <?php } else {

    ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo inkthemes_main_image(); ?></a>

    <?php

    }

    ?>

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . 'Pages:' . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>')); ?>

    <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ''); ?>

</div>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="continue"><?php _e('Continue reading &rarr;', 'dzonia'); ?></a>

<div class="tags">

<?php the_tags('Post Tagged with ', ', ', ''); ?>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace this line:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

With this line:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

That should insert your post's content instead of an excerpt.

Comment: I tried but I am unable to see the content if i remove this <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

Comment: I want that read more link. I just want to remove the excerpt

Comment: See my edit above ^^

Comment: That one also didn't worked my content is not displaying!

Comment: Not `the_post()`.  You want `the_content()` if you want to display the post's content.  `the_post()` fetches the next post for The Loop.

Comment: @PatJ Thanks! I haven't had enough caffeine this morning...

Comment: And @Thejdeep -- if you don't want post content to display at all, just remove `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a *read more* link instead, replace `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` with:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read more</a>
```

This will create the same link as the image, just with text.